# Mac, Android Studio, Emulator, SQLite database - actually find directory?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-device-monitor

I am using Android Studio on a Mac, everything on the latest version. Say I do this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
db = yourAppContext.openOrCreateDatabase("db.sqlite3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Thanks to this link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/know-where-database-is-stored-in-android-studio/

it's possible to exactly find the directory holding **your actual SQLite3 database** on the emulator as it runs:

[image]

Great stuff.

Next you can click the Pull button, and pull that file to say your desktop on the Mac.  Awesome.

But, how do you actually find **literally that folder** ("databases" in the example), **on your Mac?**

i.e., using a normal shell terminal, I want to "cd" to there.

Where is that folder, in the ordinary 'nix file structure of the host Mac computer?

Comment: It's my understanding that emulators are basically virtual machines, so accessing the db without using `adb` likely isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[`adb`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)** (Android Debug Bridge) is needed to access an emulator  device's filesystem via the command-line . If you don't already have it installed you can [download it here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html).

Once installed it's just a matter of using a few commands to view/access the files:

> 1. Open `Terminal.app`.
> 2. Execute `adb devices` (this should list your current emulator devices).
> 3. Connect to the emulator device with `adb shell` .
> 4. Change directory `cd` to the folder where your app databases are.
> 5. Type `ls` to see which database files are present.

*In Terminal it would look something like this*:

**List the emulator devices:**

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554  device
```

**Connect to device with `adb shell`**:

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 shell
```

**Change directory** <sub>(`cd`) into it's `SQLite3` database location (package name is usually `com...`):</sub>

```
adb shell
$ cd /data/data/<your app package name>/databases/
```

**List the files in the `databases` directory:**

```
adb shell
$ ls
db.sqlite3
```

That's really the basics of it! It's also possible to `push/pull` to copy files from the emulator (remote) to your (local) filesystem:

```
adb pull /data/data/com.yourpackagename.app/databases/db.sqlite3 /local/save/path
```

If Permission is denied run ADB in root mode:

```
adb root
```

More information:

- [Android Studio Command-Line Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/index.html)
- [Android Studio Command-Line SQLite3](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3.html)
- [Android Studio SDK Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html)

Comment: Note this only works on emulators... You would otherwise have to root your device.

Comment: permission denied on `cd /data/data/<your app package name>/databases/`

Answer (score 2):

or you can pull databases using this command

adb pull /data/data/com.application/databases/
for example
adb pull /data/data/com.zameen.propforce/databases/

secondly that folder is not accessible unless your device is **rooted** or you are **using emulator**

if your device is rooted. you get super user access by adb su command then you can go to this directory